# When is it okay not to put a comma, where the rule may normally apply?

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis

In this sentence:

> I will forward the log, when it is complete.

Is it permissible to remove the comma?

> I will forward the log when it is complete.

I thought sentences that are plain and can "stand on their own" (whatever that means) can get away without the comma.

When may I not use a comma, where perhaps I might in other cases at all times?  When does the usage become "bad grammar"?

Comment: Forget that "stand on their own" business. The comma here is effectively optional, but careful writers would include it *if and only if* the context is such that *when spoken aloud*, the speaker would naturally pause after the word ***log***. It's not difficult to come up with different contexts where you would expect (or *not* expect) a spoken pause.

Comment: When in doubt, leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

The "rules" of commas are perhaps the vaguest in language, and many of them more guidelines than "rules" even in the minds of those most fond of enforcing rules. And those about whether or not to have them between two clauses the vaguest of the lot.

That caveat said, you have perhaps the opposite case.

Here you have an adverbial clause *when it is complete*. It is a type of dependent clause, because it cannot stand on its own:

> When it is complete.

What does that mean? Nothing, because it needs more context.

A common rule here is that you use a comma between a dependent and independent clause if the dependent clause comes first (it does not) or is a non-restrictive relative clause (it is not). So really the question is reverse. The by-the-rules version is:

> I will forward the log when it is complete.

Which leads us to the question, can we choose to put the comma back in?

Sure, if the pause and its effect of making each clause stand apart more is desirable, then by all means do so. It will likely have an effect of making the second clause sound like an additional thought, added after the first clause was thought of.

I'm sure some stickler will disagree, but then I'm sure another stickler will argue the other way from slightly different rules.

The pause making it sound closer or further than what you mean to your ear is the law to follow. The guideline about not having a comma there is an attempt to codify what the ear does. They're not useless (sometimes we'll doubt our own ears after so long thinking about a dozen permutations of the same phrase, and sometimes the guidelines will help catch slight errors that slipped us by) but the ear is king here.

Comment: I agree with this analysis. In particular, I think that including a comma in the sentence "I will forward the log, when it is complete" carries the implication that the speaker is resisting a demand that he or she forward the log right away. In other words, a reader may take the version of the sentence with the comma in place as meaning "I will forward the log, [but I will do so only] when it is complete." The version without the comma, in contrast, reads as though it were answering the simple question "When will you forward the log?"